# Creating 3x3 Matrix using Table Function and then accessing an element

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I use the table function to create a 3x3 matrix in index notation.  I assume that I can access the element in first row and first column using `A[[1,1]]` but instead I need to use `A[[1,1,1]]`.  How can I define a 3x3 matrix so that I can access each element by using `A[[rowNum,colNum]]` notation?  Please see code below:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
A = Table[Subscript[a, i, j], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}] // MatrixForm
A[[1, 1]]
A[[1, 1, 1]]
```

Thanks

Comment: Linked topic should answer all your doubts, let me know if that is not the case.

Comment: sorry I don't see how I can access the element using A[[rowNum,colNum]].  Why do I need to use A[[1,rowNum,colNum]]?

Comment: Have you read the answer in linked topic?

Comment: Yes I did.  My goal is to use the table function to generate the matrix and not write the matrix term by term.  See code below

Comment: ClearAll["Global`*"]
A = Table[Subscript[a, i, j], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}] // MatrixForm
A[[1, 1]]
A = {{Subscript[a, 1, 1], Subscript[a, 1, 2], 
    Subscript[a, 1, 3]}, {Subscript[a, 2, 1], Subscript[a, 2, 2], 
    Subscript[a, 2, 3]}, {Subscript[a, 3, 1], Subscript[a, 3, 2], 
    Subscript[a, 3, 3]}} // MatrixForm
A[[1, 1]]

Comment: Please take a look at the second code line in the answer from linked thread. I don't see how I can add anything new.

Comment: Why not to consider performing your computations without the MatrixForm formatting then visualising the result with it (as suggested in the duplicate answer) ?